# Were the Jawas hauling away smoking debris from crashed Podracers in The Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

Tatooine's Jawas are well known as passionate scavengers and junk collectors that were usually first on the scene of a crashed starship lurking to haul its debris but in the film *Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace* we only see two Jawas - apparently as spectators (using their common expression: *"[Utinni!](https://youtu.be/0wkiHVWA98U)"*).

Are we to assume that they were camping out and waiting for the inevitable wrecks to cart away still-smoking machinery for salvage? We don't see it in the film, but is there a canon reference about the Jawas hauling away the debris during the Boonta Eve Classic?

[image: Still from The Phantom Menace where two Jawas watch a podracer]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is addressed in the *[Inside the Worlds of Episode 1: The Phantom Menace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars:_Episode_I)* factbook. Jawas do indeed try to scavenge the crashed remains of podracers.

[image: Grainy scanning of Jawas watching a podracer. The caption under the image is reproduced below.]
<sub><sup>*"For Jawas, Podraces are fabulous scavenging opportunities. These cloaked Tatooine natives work in teams to cover as much of the circuit as possible, competing with P-100 Salvage Droids to pick up scrap engine parts from crash sites"*</sup></sub>

Comment: crazy co-incidence that the factbook uses the same image as the OP

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Since the Jawas are only on-screen for a second or so and don't move much during their appearance, it's not that much of a coincidence.

Comment: This does bring into question a problem I've always had with that scene - as long as that "racetrack" is, there's only a very small portion of it that seems to be visible to spectators.  Seems like it'd be a kind of boring event to watch - you get to see the very beginning and the very end, and none of the drama in the middle. (Were there multiple laps?  I forget.)  But if there were spectators along the full length of the race, the Jawas would have nowhere to hide in order to steal stuff...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - There were camera bots all along the track. Anakin's mom has a screen that allows her to see the action and there were screens near the trackway; https://youtu.be/6AtIRu0034E?t=55

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Also really not any different than, for example, the Monaco Grand Prix, where you can see a maximum of about 5% of the course; https://www.enterf1.com/monaco-grand-prix/where-to-sit-at-monaco. Most of the excitement at events like this comes from being in the crowd, the loud noise, getting drunk, eating spicy/greasy/sugared food, chatting with friends and other racegoers, etc.  The race really is a relatively small part of the experience.

Comment: I'll admit that part escaped my memory like most of this movie.  But then in that case - how do the camera bots not notice there are Jawas all over the place?  And for that matter, why haven't any enterprising Jawas figured out a way to steal the camera bots?  Seems like it wouldn't be that hard, and I'd bet they'd sell for a good price...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I guess the key is that the Jawas (unlike the Sandpeople) want to keep on the good side of the locals.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It looks like that image is an official production still, and can be found [on the Star Wars website here](https://www.starwars.com/jawa-biography-gallery). It's not a frame grabbed from the film because there's no motion blur on the pod racer, unlike in the film itself.

Comment: @miles excellent point. And very fitting that you commented on this racing answer with your username... :-P

Comment: Thank you honorable @Valorum for your answer!

Comment: @BingoMehndra - [No problem at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM).